# Laravel prevent sending to notification channel with return statement

Tags: php, laravel, vonage

I'm trying to prevent sending to my Nexmo SMS notification channel based on some criteria in my project. I've already got some code to prevent sending to my channel in my `via` method which seems to work, but in the actual `toNexmo` function I need to run a check on the user credit for my user and then prevent sending to that channel and then run another method.

I've tried just a `return` in my if statement, and now, a `return []` which seems to throw the following error:

> local.ERROR: Invalid Message Type {"exception":"[object] (Vonage\Client\Exception\Request(code: 3):

How do I prevent the function from running if my if statement is running:

```php
/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    $preferences = json_decode($notifiable->notification_preferences);

    // if (!$notifiable->is_subscribed) {
    //     $preferences->domains->expiry = array_merge(array_diff($preferences->domains->expiry, ['nexmo']));
    // }

    return $preferences->domains->expiry;
}

/**
 * Get the Vonage / SMS representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\NexmoMessage
 */
public function toNexmo($notifiable)
{
    $availableCredit = $this->getAvailableCredit($notifiable);

    // no credit available
    if (!isset($availableCredit) || $availableCredit <= 0) {
        return []; // TODO: this part is causing the error, I just need it to stop.
    }

    // stuf

    return (new NexmoMessage)
            ->clientReference((string) $notifiable->id)
            ->content("Your domain $domain is expiring soon! Expiration date: $expirationDate");
}
```

Comment: The `toXXX()` methods are used to format a message for a delivery channel. They are not where you perform logic to decide whether or not to send the notification. These checks should be performed wherever you're doing `$user->notify(new MyNotification);` Same for the `via()` method, which only determines which channels to send the message on.

Comment: Okay, but `$user->notify()` if I were to wrap my checks in that would then prevent sending to all of my other channels. I have 4 channels, I need to omit one of them based on criteria.

Comment: `via()` returns delivery channels. So if you're eliminating one channel based on some logic that's where it should be done, not in the `toXxx()` methods.